# Livecode Geolocation not returning result

Tags: geolocation, livecode

I created a sample stack in livecode to test the `geolocation` but somehow the result is always `empty`

The sample stack can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8wt8xpnz88jsro5/Sensors.livecode?dl=0)

Executing this code: `answer mobileCanTrackLocation()` will fire `true`

`mobileStartTrackingSensor "location", true` < -- to start the tracking
`mobileStopTrackingSensor "location"` <-- to stop tracking

Here's my code for displaying in the result in the field:

```
    get mobileSensorReading("location", true) 
    if it is an array then
        combine it using return and "="
    end if
    put "Current Reading" && it & return before field "Result"
```

Anything I missed?

I am using Livecode 7.0.3

Comment: Can you give some more information. Where are you testing your application? In the simulator? On a physical device? On what kind of device?

Comment: @hliljegren I tested it using android device. I also checked the coarse location and fine location on permission settings. Also I tested using simulator.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me reliably on iOS:

```
    mobileStartTrackingSensor "location", false
    put mobileSensorReading("location",false) into tData
    mobileStopTrackingSensor "location"
```

However, I have not been able to get it to work on Android devices. It may be well to report this as a bug to LiveCode.

Comment: Thanks @Devin. I'll verify on iOS device.